# How to specify mangled names explicitly?

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I use [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/). During minification some names are mangled with same letter (for example, `a`). And this produce some issues with the 3d party lib I use. `reserved` option resolve the issue. But I still want mangle this names and explicitly specify different letters for them. How can I do this with UglifyjsWebpackPlugin?

Comment: "some issues"? Which 3rd party library? Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: @slhck it's too complex environment. You will not reproduce that. Also it's common question, because I need this feature in different cases.